# Print all numbers less than the last number in a list in python

Tags: python

How can I print only the numbers that are less than the last number in the list?

I am trying to print all numbers less than the last number in a list using python. The list is based on user input. Example numbers for user input are:

```
5
40
50
160
300
75
100 (the last number)
```

I do not want to print the first or the last number. The first number lists how many numbers in the list to check. My code is only providing the current numbers in the list. I can't figure out how to only get the numbers that are less than the last number in the list. I do not want to use functions or an array. This needs to be for/while/else/if/range or something in that realm.

```
lst = [] #the list 
n = int(input()) #user input
  
for i in range(-1, n):
    ele = int(input())
    lst.append(ele) # adding the element'

print(*lst, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly your question is?

Comment: Use `for i in range(n)` and read about [list comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you didn't use the `<` operator at all in the code?

Comment: Hello, TKO! Some hints to help you figure out the problem - you can get the last element in the list using `lst[-1]` and the first one using `lst[0]`. If you want to skip the first element in the list, just use `for i in lst[1:]`.

Comment: 1. read n.  2. read n more numbers into a list. 3. read last number.  Use a list comprehension to print only numbers in the list less than the last number OR use another `for` loop with an `if`.

Comment: I tried  if lst < ele but that didn't work.

Comment: You can't compare a list with a single element directly.  Loop over the list and compare each element.  Edit your question to show the code you tried if you are stuck.

Comment: ```less = [i for i in lst if i < lst[-1]]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list:

```
List=[5, 40, 50, 160, 300, 75, 100]
```

`List[-1]` is `100`

To print all elements smaller than `100` (the last element in the list):

```
n=int(input("Limit: "))) # Limiting number of comparisons with user input
smaller_numbers=[] # Creating a new list to store all the smaller values
for i in List[:n]: # Looping through the list to compare every element
    if i<List[-1]: # Seeing if the number is smaller than the last element of the list
        smaller_numbers.append(i) # if True the number will be appended to the new list

print(smaller_numbers)
```

### Output:

(if the user input is 8):

```
[5, 40, 50, 75]
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!!!! Truly appreciated! Yungmaz13 your response helped me to understand what I was missing. I didn't know you could create a list to store numbers from another list. A lot more studying to do. Super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @TKO No problem! :) Try to be clearer next time though, it was hard understanding what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_check(list):
 big_number = list[-1]
 for I in list[1:]:
     if I < big_number:
        print(I)
```

I don't understand how you want the user input to play a part in this, but if you run a list through this it will check the last number against all numbers in the list not including the first number.

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to sort the items, because then when you might hit the items that are larger, you could stop the checking.  I'd probably sort the list into a new list and try to check on efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

This code will print the numbers less and add to list

```
number1 = 100
number2 = 0
list1 = []
while True:
    number2 += 1
    list1.append(number2)
    if number2 == number1:
        list1.remove(number1)
        break
print(list1)
```

Comment: I think the asker wanted the numbers _in the list_ that are less than the final element; this code prints _all_ numbers between 1 and 99.